# ColdFusion collection / search won't populate

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo

I am new to using cfcollection and cfsearch, but I gave it a go and it seemed to work. Then, I purged the collection and it stopeed working. I then, decided that I would delete the collection and start over. The collection deleted fine, but now the same code won't return any results.

My query returns 5 results that the collection and subsequent search should be picking up, but the returned search is empty, even when I specify a wildcard * in my criteria.

Is there anything wrong with my code below? No errors or anything, just blank results.

```
public void function ajax() { 

    param name="params.keywords" default="SoundCloud";

    onlyProvides("json");

    local.collectionPath = expandPath( "./" ) & "collections/";

    // Delete
    /*
    collection 
        action="delete" 
        collection="pincollection" 
        path="#local.collectionPath#";
    */

    collection 
        action="list" 
        name="local.collectionList";

    local.collectionList = valueList(collectionList.name);

    if ( ! listFind(local.collectionList, "pincollection") ) {

        collection 
            action="create" 
            collection="pincollection" 
            engine="solr" 
            categories="yes"
            path="#local.collectionPath#";

    }

    local.pins = model("pin").findAll(

        include     = "user", 
        order       = "createdat DESC"

    );

    index 
        collection="pincollection" 
        action="update" 
        type="custom" 
        title="title"
        body="description" 
        custom1="latitude"
        custom2="longitude"
        custom3="typeid"
        custom4="createdAt"
        custom5="updatedAt"
        query="local.pins"
        category="typeid"
        key="id";

    search 
        name="local.pinSearch" 
        collection="pincollection" 
        contextHighlightBegin="<strong>" 
        contextHighlightEnd="</strong>" 
        category="2,1" 
        maxrows="100"
        criteria="•";


    writeDump(var=local.pinSearch); // Empty search query.
    writeDump(var=local.pins, abort=true); // Original query returns 5 results.

    renderWith(data=local.pinSearch, layout=false);

}
```

I am using Railo.

I can see that in my collections folder, a folder for my collection has been created, but this does not contain any files.

I'm a newbie at using ColdFusion / Railo for search. It seems straight-forward, but I'm stumped.

Thanks,
Mikey.

PS - I am using CFWheels, hence some CFWheels specific functions. These can be ignored.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should not be indexing the data EVERY time you want to do a search. Indexing should be done as a separate process - usually when you add/update/delete items from database or adding/updating/deleting documents from your system. Your collection should be created ONCE and you should have a separate process to rebuild it if necessary.

Comment: @ScottStroz Thanks. So, should I place this within the condition that the "create" currently sits in? So, if it doesn't exist, we create and then populate it, otherwise just search as normal? Sounds logical. I'm all new to this. Still displaying no results however.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. When I have used search collections, I make sure that any insert/update/delete operations also update the collection. Also, I have a process that would purge the collection and reindex - inside here is where I would put a check to see if the collection existed, if not, create it, then index.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go too far with troubleshooting this, consider switching to a dedicated Solr server if you can.  We quickly hit the limits of Solr in CF9 years ago and used the CFSolrLib project by Shannon Hicks to connect to a fresh install of Solr on Tomcat.  Just some of the benefits to this are:

- Reducing overhead for your CF server.
- Indexing performance boost.
- Separates search related troubleshooting from the rest of your application (like in your case).
- You gain the freedom of making changes/upgrades to your Solr server independently.

Shannon's project on github: https://github.com/iotashan/cfsolrlib

MC